# Making blocks optional and conditional entry where there is no header name

Tags: json

I am trying to write a json schema to import a csv file. A simplified version of the file is:

000,OUTCOME,111,20220320,FT

001,A.Name1,,,A,

002,A.Name2,,20220101,C,

999,2

000 is a header block

001 & 002 are the body and can have multiple instances. Structurally they are the same

999 is the trailer

the schema I have is

```
{
"conf_name": "FileTest",
"has_blocks": true,
"has_headers": false,
"enabled_extensions": [
    {
        "extension": "csv",
        "delimiter": ","
    }
],
"file_type": "FileTest",
"columns": [
    {
        "blockName": "000",
        "name": "",
        "startPosition": "",
        "maxLength": "",
        "minLength": "",
        "data": {
            "mandatory": "M",
            "type": "text",
            "format": "",
            "values": [
                "OUTCOME"
            ],
            "conditional": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "blockName": "000",
        "name": "",
        "startPosition": "",
        "maxLength": "",
        "minLength": "",
        "data": {
            "mandatory": "M",
            "type": "int",
            "format": "",
            "values": "",
            "conditional": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "blockName": "000",
        "name": "",
        "startPosition": "",
        "maxLength": "",
        "minLength": "",
        "data": {
            "mandatory": "M",
            "type": "date",
            "format": "yyyyMMdd",
            "values": "",
            "conditional": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "blockName": "000",
        "name": "",
        "startPosition": "",
        "maxLength": "",
        "minLength": "",
        "data": {
            "mandatory": "M",
            "type": "text",
            "format": "",
            "values": "",
            "conditional": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "blockName": "001",
        "name": "",
        "startPosition": "",
        "maxLength": "",
        "minLength": "",
        "data": {
            "mandatory": "M",
            "type": "text",
            "format": "",
            "values": "",
            "conditional": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "blockName": "001",
        "name": "",
        "startPosition": "",
        "maxLength": "",
        "minLength": "",
        "data": {
            "mandatory": "O",
            "type": "text",
            "format": "",
            "values": "",
            "conditional": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "blockName": "001",
        "name": "",
        "startPosition": "",
        "maxLength": "",
        "minLength": "",
        "data": {
            "mandatory": "C",
            "type": "date",
            "format": "yyyyMMdd",
            "values": "",
            "conditional": {
                "columnName": "Column5",
                "operation": "==C THEN NOTEMPTY",
                "value": ""
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "blockName": "001",
        "name": "Column5",
        "startPosition": "",
        "maxLength": "",
        "minLength": "",
        "data": {
            "mandatory": "M",
            "type": "text",
            "format": "",
            "values": [
                "A",
                "B",
                "C"
            ],
            "conditional": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "blockName": "001",
        "name": "",
        "startPosition": "",
        "maxLength": "",
        "minLength": "",
        "data": {
            "mandatory": "O",
            "type": "text",
            "format": "",
            "values": [
                "Y",
                "N"
            ],
            "conditional": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "blockName": "002",
        "name": "",
        "startPosition": "",
        "maxLength": "",
        "minLength": "",
        "data": {
            "mandatory": "M",
            "type": "text",
            "format": "",
            "values": "",
            "conditional": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "blockName": "002",
        "name": "",
        "startPosition": "",
        "maxLength": "",
        "minLength": "",
        "data": {
            "mandatory": "O",
            "type": "text",
            "format": "",
            "values": "",
            "conditional": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "blockName": "002",
        "name": "",
        "startPosition": "",
        "maxLength": "",
        "minLength": "",
        "data": {
            "mandatory": "C",
            "type": "date",
            "format": "yyyyMMdd",
            "values": "",
            "conditional": {
                "columnName": "Column5",
                "operation": "==C THEN NOTEMPTY",
                "value": ""
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "blockName": "002",
        "name": "",
        "startPosition": "",
        "maxLength": "",
        "minLength": "",
        "data": {
            "mandatory": "M",
            "type": "text",
            "format": "",
            "values": [
                "A",
                "B",
                "C"
            ],
            "conditional": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "blockName": "002",
        "name": "",
        "startPosition": "",
        "maxLength": "",
        "minLength": "",
        "data": {
            "mandatory": "O",
            "type": "text",
            "format": "",
            "values": [
                "Y",
                "N"
            ],
            "conditional": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "blockName": "999",
        "name": "",
        "startPosition": "",
        "maxLength": "",
        "minLength": "",
        "data": {
            "mandatory": "M",
            "type": "int",
            "format": "",
            "values": "",
            "conditional": ""
        }
    }
]
```

}

I apologise now if that is an affront to JSON users everywhere!
This works if there are both 001 and 002 lines in the file, but I've now been told that there may times when the file is all 001 or 002 but not both. Is there a way to make them optional?  "oneOf" seemed likely, but I could not fathom how to use it in this situation.
My other issue was with the conditional entry. The data does not have a header row so I'm not sure how to check it. The intention is that if the 5th column contains a "C" then the 4th should have a date in it.
Any help would be gratefully received. Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on the JSON you shared in your question? It does not look like jsonschema. How are you consuming it? What kind of validator are you using?

Comment: Thank you for looking at this @Byted. I apologise but I am very much working from a position of ignorance!  This is being used to validate files being imported on a web portal. One user has to write the schema in order to validate the files of other users.The developers, who are not very forthcoming, described this as JSON schema. I could not find anything similar when I searched but if you are saying it doesn't look like JSON schema then that would explain that. It may be something they custom created